# Java runtime query of local maven repository

Tags: java, maven

In my application, I want to get a 'view' of the local maven repository. The application is used to start another Java application (via `ProcessBuilder`), and allows users to add/replace libraries on the classpath. Part of this will provide a view of the artifacts in a user's local maven repository that could be used on the subsequent classpath.

Given an `M2_HOME` setting, I can get the `settings.xml` and from that the directory that the local maven repository is stored in (`<localRepository>`).

I could then do a file system query to get the jars, poms etc. that are in the user's local maven repository, determining the `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`, `packaging` etc. from the file path and filename.

However, I am wondering whether there is scope to do this through the maven machinery - i.e. using maven libraries. If possible, that strikes me as being the correct / clever way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at following maven dependencies,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>      
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Something on following line

1. RepositorySystem and LegacyRepositorySystem classes
2. RepositorySystem `ArtifactRepository createLocalRepository( File localRepository )` method.

You might still need to inspect your local maven installation conf if local repository is set to other than ${user.dir}/.m2

---

I have just realized that it does not give a complete artifactory view. Could you check the following,

1. org.apache.maven.index.Scanner
2. org.apache.maven.index.DefaultScanner

This is probably used in eclipse Maven repositories view. See following,

[image]

Comment: How does an `ArtificactRepository` provide a view of the `Artifact`s that it already contains?